# Wpf Comboxbox selectable default item

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a comboxbox that is databound to an observablecollection from my viewmodel. I can get my list to populate with the data but I also would like to add a default item like "--All Models--". The code below displays "--All Models--" as the default item but it is not selectable if you select another item.

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Items}">
    <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <ComboBox x:Name="cb" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="tb" Text="--Choose One--" IsHitTestVisible="False" Visibility="Hidden"/>
            </Grid>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger SourceName="cb" Property="SelectedItem" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter TargetName="tb" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </Trigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
</ContentControl>
```

I have tried with a compositecollection but that does not seem to to work.  Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build the view interaction logic into the viewmodel. my suggestion make the Observable collection type a viewmodel that is populated by the source list, plus one more viewmodel for the "not selected" item.

something like

```
public class ItemViewModel
{
     public string Description { get; set; }
     public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{        
    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items { get; set; } // Bound to ContentControl

    private void Init()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();
        Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { Description = "--choice one--" , Id = null });
        Items.AddRange(Model.Items.Select(i=> new ItemViewModel() { Description = i.Description , Id = i.Id }));
    }
}
```

Then you can process SelectedItem's Id with the null sematic.

Answer (score 4):

`CompositeCollection` should work, if you know how to use it that is; one important thing about it is that it *does not* inherit a `DataContext`, this means you need to reference your source in some other manner, further if that method is `x:Reference` you may not create a cyclic reference, this can be avoided by placing the collection in the Resources of the element referenced. e.g.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CompositeCollection x:Key="compCollection">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="-- All Models --"/>
        <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding MyCollection, Source={x:Reference Window}}"/>
    </CompositeCollection>
    ...
</Window.Resources>
```

You can then just use this via `ItemsSource="{StaticResource compCollection}"`.

Comment: This is a much neater answer. Much cleaner from an MVVM perspective.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your collection generic type to `object` and add there --All Models-- thing.